# Popover position in div with position absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with popover position.

**This is what it looks like:**

[image]

**This is what it is supposed to look like:**

[image]

**With `position: relative;` on the timetable, the popover works, but the timetable doesn't:**

[image]

**Code:**

In my html file I have one div with position: relative;

```
    <div id="bg-timetable" class="bg-timetable"/>
```

In my `JS`, I create in it a small div with timetable with that has `position: absolute;`. For event I have a function:

```
   function createDivEvent(event) {
        var start = new Time(event.startTime);
        var end = new Time(event.endTime);

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("event");

        div.id = event.id;
        div.style.top =  start.getPercent() + "%";
        div.style.height = (end.getPercent() - start.getPercent()) + "%";
        div.innerHTML = event.subject.name + " (" + event.place.name + ")";

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('tabindex', "0");
        a.setAttribute('data-toggle','popover');
        a.setAttribute('data-content','Some content inside the popover');
        a.setAttribute('title',div.innerHTML);

        a.appendChild(div);

        var d = new Date(event.date)
        document.getElementById(weekday[d.getDay()]).appendChild(a);
    }
```

Can You help me?

Comment: What do you *want* to happen?

Comment: When I click my div with subject I want to show details over the subject in my timetable. Like this: http://i.imgur.com/WS54UID.png or this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo-1

Comment: Ok. I find that to be a bit clearer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fix it:

```
function createDivEvent(event) {
        var start = new Time(event.startTime);
        var end = new Time(event.endTime);

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = event.id;
        div.innerHTML = event.subject.name + " (" + event.place.name + ")";

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('tabindex', "0");
        a.setAttribute('data-toggle','popover');
        a.setAttribute('data-content','Some content inside the popover');
        a.setAttribute('title',div.innerHTML);
        a.setAttribute('data-placement',"top");
        a.appendChild(div);
        a.style.top =  start.getPercent() + "%";
        a.style.height = (end.getPercent() - start.getPercent()) + "%";
        a.classList.add("event");

        var d = new Date(event.date)
        document.getElementById(weekday[d.getDay()]).appendChild(a);
    }
```

Css:

```
a.event {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be beneficial if you accept your answer so that it is obvious that you solved your solution. (If you decide to do this -- please do :) -- click the green checkmark below the [upvote/downvote] arrows.) Glad you solved your problem. :)